# Listing all sub-pages?

Tags: php, functions, pages, list, listing

I'm wondering how to write a list of sub-pages of actually visited page.

So I have 2 pages and 3 sub-pages for each:

```
Colors [page]
- Red [child of Colors - subpage]
- Blue [child of Colors - subpage]
- Green [child of Colors - subpage]

Numbers [page]
- One [child of Numbers - subpage]
- Two [child of Numbers - subpage]
- Three [child of Numbers - subpage]
```

And when user visits "Colors" page then my code outputs Red/Blue/Green and if he does vist Numbers it shows One/Two/Three.

I'm sure wp_list_pages will do the thing easy, but I'm not sure about parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy just pass it the $id off which to get the children

```
  global $id;
  wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$id");
```

of if you want in the loop then

```
 wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$post->ID");
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. The first code shows nothing. The second shows the list of all pages & sub-pages. Are you sure this should work inside of a widget? BTW when I type "echo $id" it echoes ID of the SIDEBAR.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from a page template I use to list subpages:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: your code also shows list of all pages and sub-pages.