# $post>ID displays wrong post ID

Tags: widgets, sidebar, posts, loop

I've asked a question about listing all sub-pages before:

[Listing all sub-pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11091/listing-all-sub-pages)

But all the questions were wrong.

Anyways, I have now simpler question.

```
global $post;
echo $post>ID
```

Works totally fine, but while on pages sidebars only. When it's next to the blog loop (in a blog section) it goes crazy, for example Blog has ID of 216 (and $post>ID in loop.php shows 216), but the $post>ID in the sidebar shows 87. Why is this happening? How to fix that?

Thank you!

[edit]

I have a suspicion that loop and sidebar are both included in index page separately and loop is getting different post ID than sidebar. The big question is how to change that.

[edit for Rarst]

```
 wp_reset_postdata();

                global $post;

                $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
                echo $children;
```

Gives the same result. It works with pages, not blog. I have a normal loop, as like in Twenty Ten for example.

Comment: Hmm... Are you trying to make it work on page with loop of multiple posts? Which post's ID you expect to get?

Comment: @Rarst, exactly. I have a few PAGES and I want to display all children (sub-pages) of them. So when user visits Blog I want it to display Blog children. So I may be wrong and should go for page ID not post ID? But $page>id displays list of all pages everywhere. Af.

Comment: Where are you calling this code, which file, and where in the file? (and, inside a function or just in the file?).

Comment: @t31os, inside a widget that is included in a sidebar. It's inside function widget( $args, $instance ) { } as widgets output.

Comment: The front page in TwentyTen isn’t a page, it is an archive. Archives don’t have children. You have to use a page on front to get children.

Comment: Assuming you're not using `query_posts` to perform other queries somewhere between when the main loop occurs and when the sidebar gets output, `$wp_query->post` should hold an object of the first post(or page/custom type) from the main query, you could use that to determine ID, eg. `$wp_query->post->ID`.

Comment: Or perhaps even.. `$wp_query->get_queried_object_id()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand correctly you are trying to display a list of child pages of a page in a widget, if so then first check if you are on a page using the conditional tag `is_page()`
then  you can use $wp_query->get_queried_object_id() like t31os has pointed out so your widget display function should look like this:

```
if (is_page()){
    Global $wp_query;
    $current_page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$current_page_id.'&echo=0');
    echo $children;
}
```

So only if you are on a page this code will run

Comment: your code works fine but displays nothing on "Blog". So the effect is almost the same as with wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0'); . I want to display all sub pages on EVERY page, including the blog one! :)

Comment: there you go , that means that your bolg is not a page but probably a category, in that case you don't need child pages , you need posts, in that category.

Comment: oh my God, you're a genius and I am a dumba... ;)

Answer (score 5):

`$post` changes every time `the_post()` or `setup_postdata()` are used - which is in most of the loops.

Use `wp_reset_postdata()` to kick it back to original data.

**Edit**

`$post` holds data of **individual** post, set up during the Loop. It makes no sense to use it out of that context.

To process multiple pages you need to query for them (with `get_pages()` for example) and work with that.

Comment: check the last edit :(